# Linkbutton does not trigger jquery submit event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, linkbutton

What below won't work with any linkbutton, but works fine with all button controls.

```
 $('form').live("submit", function () {
    ShowProgress();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you tag ASP.Net, I assume submit is a LinkButton. If so, you need to use

```
'#<%= SubmitLinkButton.ClientID %>'
```

Comment: Sorry, I might be missing something. Is there any ID in the OP's script?

Answer (score 2):

Because `LinkButtons` do postback in a different way. While `Button` controls are real buttons that actually submit the form, `LinkButton` are actually links. They do not submit a form, but rather run a certain script on click that calls `_doPostBack` function.